# Is it mandatory to run celery as daemon in production

Tags: celery

I have seen celery documentation that its advisable to run celery as daemon process. In my case each celery worker is a docker container whose sole purpose is to execute celery tasks. In that scnario also, is it recommended to execute as daemon process?

Answer (score 2):

No, if Celery worker runs inside a container there is no need to run it as daemon.